# Argument Exception Occured while Navigating to a Page

Tags: windows-phone

I am facing issue when Navigting to a page,and exception occurs in filename.g.cs file.This issue all started when i was trying to switch the PhoneApplicationPage to folder ,I dont find any issue with .xaml or .xaml.cs file.it occurs in g.cs file[image]

Answer (score 0):

An exception on this specific line usually means there's something wrong in your XAML code. Unfortunately, those errors can be hard to track, so here is a few recommendations:

- Check the details of your exception, especially the callstack and the inner exception. It can provide more information on which part of the XAML is wrong
- Start removing elements from your XAML until the exception stops being raised. This way, you can know exactly where the error is. Start by the styles, resources, and bindings, as they are the most likely culprits.